# React: String automatically converted to [object promise] when called from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm developing the front-end for my spring boot application. I set up an initial call wrapped in a useEffect() React.js function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
            '/myapi/' + auth.authState.id
          );

        setData(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
    getData();
    }, [fetchContext]);
```

The data returned isn't comprehensive, and needs further call to retrieve other piece of information, for example this initial call return an employee id, but if I want to retrieve his name and display it I need a sub-sequential call, and here I'm experiencing tons of issues:

```
    const getEmployeeName = async id => {
        try {
          const name = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
            '/employeeName/' + id
          );

          console.log((name["data"]));  // <= Correctly display the name
          return name["data"];          // return an [Object promise], 
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
```

I tried to wrap the return call inside a `Promise.resolve()` function, but didn't solve the problem. Upon reading to similar questions here on stackoverflow, most of the answers suggested to create a callback function or use the await keyword (as I've done), but unfortunately didn't solve the issue. I admit that this may not be the most elegant way to do it, as I'm still learning JS/React I'm open to suggestions on how to improve the api calls.

```
var output = Object.values(data).map((index) =>
<Appointment
  key={index["storeID"].toString()}
  // other irrelevant props
  employee={name} 
  approved={index["approved"]}
/>);
return output;
```

Comment: What is `id` being passed to `getEmployeeName`? You also can't have asynchronous code in the render of a component as the render should be a pure function without side-effects.

Comment: Got it. So I should remove the function from the render of the <Appointment/> component, how am I gonna change the code now tho? id is a Long value.

Comment: You'll probably move the code into the use effect, after the first result comes back. I can type out an example, but i don't know where `index` in `index['employeeID']` comes from. Is index part of the data returned by the employeename fetch?

Comment: Well, my presumption is that whatever you are rendering into `Appointment` components is related to `data` state you set in the `useEffect`. If this is correct then you can make the additional requests in the hook. It's clear that `index.employeeID` is the `id` being used to fetch additional data, we're asking what `index` is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, index is a temp variable I created for looping through the array of objects returned by the first fetch: Object.values(appointmentsData).map((index) => <Appointment props />

Answer (score 1):

Async functions *always* return promises. Any code that needs to interact with the value needs to either call .then on the promise, or be in an async function and await the promise.

In your case, you should just need to move your code into the existing `useEffect`, and `setState` when you're done. I'm assuming that the employeeID is part of the data returned by the first fetch:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
        "/myapi/" + auth.authState.id
      );

      setData(data);

      const name = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(
         '/employeeName/' + data.employeeID
      );

      setName(name.data);      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  getData();
}, [fetchContext]);

// ...
var output = Object.values(appointmentsData).map((index) =>
<Appointment
  key={index["storeID"].toString()}
  // other irrelevant props
  employee={name} 
  approved={index["approved"]}
/>);
return output;
```

Note that the above code will do a rerender once it has the data (but no name), and another later when you have the name. If you want to wait until both fetches are complete, simply move the `setData(data)` down next to the setName